# Why can I not use inplace division operator when dividing numpy vector by numpy norm

Tags: python, numpy

This code executes without a problem:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 3])
x = x / np.linalg.norm(x)
```

But this code crashes:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 3])
x /= np.linalg.norm(x)
```

With the error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

Why?

Comment: Are you expecting to get deeper answers than "because numpy developers did not implement it" ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to follow with the pycharm debugger to see exactly what is going wrong, but I can't find out exactly where the TypeError occurs, it actually looks from the debugger as if the "faulty" line with the in place operator passes, but that seems strange.

Comment: Does the exception traceback not tell you exactly where the TypeError occurs?

Comment: Note that the error message focuses on the `output`, and specifically the dtypes (typecode), 'd' and 'l' (see `np.typecodes`).

Comment: Hymns, I mean I couldn't make out how it got from the line it points out to throwing the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, because numpy cares about types, as the error suggests ("... could not be coerced ... 'same_kind'").

You are creating `x` as an array of integers, but `np.linalg.norm(x)` returns a float, forcing `x / np.linalg.norm(x)` to return an array of floats.

If you create `x` as an array of floats:

```
x = np.array([1.0, 3.0])
```

then it will work

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1.0, 3.0])
x /= np.linalg.norm(x)
print(x)
# [0.31622777 0.9486833 ]
```

Comment: But why then does numpy not care about types in the first example? `x / np.linalg.norm(x)` actually runs fine.

Comment: @Sahand because it is not in-place. It simply tells `x` to reference a new location in memory. It is not much different than doing `x = 7`, nothing to do with `numpy`