# Numpy broadcasting is not supported by the operant /=

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am following the Deep Learning course on Coursera.

I found out that when making a matrix division, like the following:

```
x_norm = np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
x = x / x_norm
```

It works fine. But when I was the statement instead:

```
x /= x_norm
```

It does not work, why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use /= on numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948308/cant-use-on-numpy-array)

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work'?  Is there an error, or just a unexpected value?  Does the error mention `broadcasting`?  (I get a `casting error` message.)

Comment: @hpaulj There is an error: ```TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''.```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I not use inplace division operator when dividing numpy vector by numpy norm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548336/why-can-i-not-use-inplace-division-operator-when-dividing-numpy-vector-by-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is an integer dtype array, you'll get this `casting` error:

```
In [1]: x = np.arange(1,4)
In [2]: x /= 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [2] in <cell line: 1>
    x /= 10
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'true_divide' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

No such problems if the array if floats:

```
In [3]: y = x.astype(float)
In [4]: y /= 10
In [5]: y
Out[5]: array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
```

`*= 0.1` would also raise a casting error.  Anything that tries to put a float in an int array.  Assignments like `x[:] = 1.1` silently cast the floats to integer - that's a more frequent cause of puzzlement.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = x/x_norm #instead of x /= x_norm
```